# How to identify if the quick create form is opened from the top nav bar or from the new button in lookup field

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9, dynamics-crm-uci

Click on the new button in the project template lookup field of the project entity,this opens a quick create form which will have all the fields

Also click on the new button from the top upper right corner of nav bar and select project entity. This also opens a quick create form with all the fields.

Now I want to distinguish from where the quick create form is opened(from the lookup new button or from the nav bar).
I would like to have a solution for this in UCI not in web client

Answer (score 0):

Literally No way.

The same Quick create form is opened in exact same way from both Lookup (New +) and Top Navigation bar Quick create button (+).

```
https://abc.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/GetClientMetadata(ClientMetadataQuery=@ClientMetadataQuery)?@ClientMetadataQuery={%22MetadataType%22:%22form%22,%22MetadataSubtype%22:%22QuickCreate%22,%22EntityLogicalName%22:%22contact%22,%22MetadataId%22:null,%22MetadataNames%22:[],%22GetDefault%22:true,%22DependencyDepth%22:%22OnDemandWithContext%22,%22ChangedAfter%22:%22777574980%22,%22Exclude%22:[],%22AppId%22:%22edcd61cf-1f0c-e811-a95f-000d3a18032d%22}
```

Probably can think about workaround, when we understand what you are trying to achieve.

Atleast Quick create form opened from Subgrid will have pre-populated parent lookup to identify the source. This is like dead end.